# Using JQuery Slidetoggle() on a list of many items

Tags: jquery, css

I want to do a list of people, and when the div is clicked on, their timetable is shown below (I assume the slidetoggle() method is the best here?).

Anyways all the tutorials I can find are for an individual simple thing. How would I make it so if a name is clicked out of many names, then only their timetable displays below?

Im on these kind of lines:

```
<div class="tutor">
<h2>Joe Bloggs</h2>
<img>(a dynamic arrow pointing up or down depending on the current toggle)</img>
    <div class="calendar">
        Calendar hide or show
    </div>
<div>
```

I guess its all around the use of $this keyword but I'm still not 100% sure how to use that!!

Many thanks,

Rick

Comment: I have this old fiddle laying around that I made ages ago. http://jsfiddle.net/7E7zp/3/ - should do what you want!

Comment: take a look at jQueryUI accordion.. I think that will be a good solution for your issue. http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

```
// Bind click event to all elements with the "tutor"-class
$(".tutor").click(function() { 
    // When one is clicked, call slideToggle on the div with class "calendar" it contains
    $(this).children(".calendar").slideToggle();
    // Toggle a class on the child img which specifies background-image/position
    $(this).children("img").toggleClass(".someClass");
});
```

Hope this helped :)